# The trust result is always kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, security-framework

I'm trying to verify that a certificate has not expired with SecTrustEvaluate function, but I found the SecTrustEvaluate function always returns kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure. Does the iOS security framework can not work with a DER certificate?

Can anyone provide any sample code for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just call SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates before SecTrustEvaluate.
[see here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/433913)

Comment: I don't see how SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates helps... that seems to be for setting trusted root certs explicitly. Also the link appears to be dead.